# Convert string to date in SQLite and comparing with current date

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE `FormMapping` (
    `PatNum`    TEXT,
    `FormName`  TEXT,
    `SheetNum`  TEXT,
    `IsCompleted`   TEXT,
    `RecordDate`    TEXT,
    `FormOrder` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`PatNum`,`SheetNum`)
);
```

above is my table structure

RecordDate formate is "MM/dd/yyyy"

How to convert "RecordDate" in date and comparing with current date in SQLite?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with iOS and Android?

Comment: not a valid question

Comment: SQLite has no "date object"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After done too many efforts I resolved the issue and query is as below,

```
DELETE FROM FormMapping WHERE strftime(substr(RecordDate, 7, 4) ||'-'||substr(RecordDate, 1, 2) ||'-'|| substr(RecordDate, 4, 2)) < DATE('now','-7 day')
```

Thanks everyone for support.

Answer (score -1):

You can try converting the current date instead and then comparing it with value in db

```
 public static String simplerDate() {

        try {
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd ''yy, HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            //Log.i(Utils.class.getSimpleName(), "simplerDate: " + pe);
            return "N/A";
        }
    }
```